# what is the Time Complexity of a nested loop in a recursive function?

Tags: python, algorithm, time-complexity, big-o

I have a recursive function with a nested loop.I’m looking for what is the time complexity? Here is the function

```
def csFirstUniqueChar(input_str,letter = 0,num = 1):
    if letter == len(input_str):
        return -1
    for x in range(len(input_str)): 
        if x == letter:
            continue
        if input_str[x] == input_str[letter]:
            num += 1
    if num == 1:
            return letter
    else:
        return csFirstUniqueChar(input_str,letter + 1,1)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose `n` is the length of `input_str`. The algorithm can iterate `n` times recursively in the worst case, i.e., in each recursive call `letter` will be increased by `1` and it can be continued up to `n`. In each iteration, the wors case is `O(n)` (running the loop completely). Hence, the time complexity is `O(n^2)`.